# Tomcat web page does not open with Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, servlets

I add spring-5.2.9.RELEASE-dist as a library(lib). But I could'nt open index.jsp file that includes just html Hello World message.How could I fix what following error?

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Description : The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

```
package com.aaa.aaa;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

@Component
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @RequestMapping("/aaa")
    public String showPage(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

MyServlet.java

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <display-name>secondApp</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering />

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.aaa.aaa" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

[image: Project]

[image: Tomcat Configuration]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>secondApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>secondApp</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

pom.xml

Comment: In MyServlet class, try to use @Controller , in place of 'Component'.

Comment: I tried. But nothing changed. Im looking "localhost:8081/secondApp/hamza","localhost:8081/secondApp/","localhost:8081/hamza" . Page not found.

Comment: Don't extend `HttpServlet`, use `@Controller` instead of `@Component`. I'm also not sure what you added, as you are using maven you should add at least a dependency on `spring-webmvc` in there.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried but. Nothing changed. I added my pom.xml at question. Could you help me why I didnt see index.jsp page.

Comment: You must be missing something, check this example it may help you https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-multiple-view-page-example